# get_theme_mod outputs number when using WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control

Tags: php, functions, customization, theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I have added a few sections to the customizer but am having trouble when trying to call the image I have defined. The back end works great but when I call it using `get_theme_mod` it echos a two digit number, like 23. I have several sections in the theme customizer (non-images) and don't have any issues.

In **functions.php** (simplified to just this one example):

```
function theme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'theme_about' , array(
    'title'      => __( 'About', 'theme' ),
    'description' => 'Add phone, email, and social buttons'
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'about_facebook_logo' );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'about_facebook_logo' , array(
    'label' => __('Facebook Image', 'theme'),
    'section' => 'theme_about',
    'settings' => 'about_facebook_logo',
    'flex_width'  => true,
    'flex_height' => true,
    'width'       => 46,
    'height'      => 46,
    ) ));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'theme_customize_register' );
```

In my **footer.php**:

```
<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'about_facebook_logo' ); ?>
```

This outputs the number 23.

**ANSWER**

Thanks to [Rarst's](http:///users/847/rarst) thoughts below, I was able to come up with a solution.

```
<?php $fbID = get_theme_mod( 'about_facebook_logo' );
      echo wp_get_attachment_url( $fbID ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Customizer part of code, but my immediate guess would that number is *attachment ID* for the uploaded image.

IDs are most typical and reliable way to store connection to particular media item within WP installation. It is trivial to get *from* ID *to* other representations, such as URLs to different image sizes. However it is quite challenging to go in reverse direction, such as determine ID (if any) for *arbitraty* image URL.

You can check if number matches up with ID in admin (typically exposed in URL) and use API functions on it (such as `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` and others).

Comment: That was my thought too but according to several sources I've found online my syntax should produce the result I'm looking for...

Comment: That got me thinking and I was able to grab the URL using:  `$fbID = get_theme_mod( 'about_facebook_logo' ); echo wp_get_attachment_url( $fbID );`